# Yahtzee two pair can't get any value

Tags: java

I am in a beginner's java class. I have had this Yahtzee program now for weeks and I still cannot get this figured out.

Having problem getting a points from my `checkTwopairs()`. `checkTwopairs()` can see if there is a two pair. But I have a hard problem getting the points out of it. Any good way to do it?

```
public int checknumber(int nr) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Dice d : diceList) {
            if (d.getValue() == nr ){
                sum++;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

public void checkTwopairs() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            int a = checknumber(i);
            if (a == 2) {
                if (twopair == true && a == 2) {
                } else {
                    twopair = true;
                }
            }
        }
        twopair = false;
    }
```

Comment: Your checkTwopairs method will always set `twopair` equal to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for 2 pairs, meaning you get dice with {5,5,2,2,1} where you have 2 pairs -- a pair of 5's, and a pair of 2's.

I think you may be looking for something like this to modify your code:

```
public void checkTwopairs() {
    boolean firstPair = false;              // New local variable.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        int a = checknumber(i);
        if (a == 2) {
          //if (twopair == true && a == 2)  <--- This second clause is unnecessary as we can only get here if a == 2
            if (firstPair == true) {
                twopair = true;
                return;                     //This returns the method, so twopair cannot be set to false if two pairs are found
            } else {
                firstPair = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //Checked all dice, less than two pairs were found. 
    twopair = false;
}
```

Comment: `firstPair == true`? `firstPair == ((1 != 0) == (true != false))` also works

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-method solution to replace both of those methods:

```
public void checkTwoPairs() {
     int numPairs = 0;
     //two pairs haven't been found yet
     boolean twoPair = false;
     //for each possible number
     for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
         int sum = 0;
         //for each dice object 
         for(Dice d : diceList) {
            //if i is the dice value
            if(d.getValue() == i) {
              //increment the number of matches
              sum++;
            }
         }
        //sum % 2   - gives you the number of pairs for that number checked
        numPairs += (sum%2);
        //if you have 2 pairs
        if(numPairs == 2) {
             //set twoPair = true   ... and break out of the loop
             twoPair = true;
             break;
        }
        //if you don't have 2 pairs yet, go back through the loop
   }
}
```